# installing pip on Windows 10

Tags: pip, windows-10

I ran `get-pip.py` and it reported:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be
>   maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support
>   for Python 2.7. Collecting pip   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: pip   Found existing installation: pip
>   19.0.3
>       Uninstalling pip-19.0.3:
>         Successfully uninstalled pip-19.0.3 Successfully installed pip-19.0.3

=======================

```
Directory of C:\Python27\Scripts

02/23/2019  03:19 AM    <DIR>          .

02/23/2019  03:19 AM    <DIR>          ..
08/15/2018  12:19 AM            93,025 chardetect.exe

12/31/2017  01:34 PM            89,449 easy_install-2.7.exe

12/31/2017  01:34 PM            89,449 easy_install.exe

12/31/2017  01:41 PM               792 f2py.py

12/31/2017  01:41 PM               998 f2py.pyc

02/23/2019  03:19 AM            93,016 pip.exe

02/23/2019  03:19 AM            93,016 pip2.7.exe

02/23/2019  03:19 AM            93,016 pip2.exe

12/31/2017  03:54 PM            16,260 runxlrd.py

12/31/2017  03:54 PM            15,143 runxlrd.pyc

12/31/2017  03:44 PM             1,960 vba_extract.py

12/31/2017  03:44 PM             1,379 vba_extract.pyc

12/31/2017  01:34 PM            89,428 wheel.exe

              13 File(s)        676,931 bytes

               2 Dir(s)  19,568,193,536 bytes free

C:\Python27\Scripts>pip

C:\Python27\Scripts>
================================
```

`pip.exe` is now in my `C:\Python27\Scripts` directory. I opened up the windows command prompt (as administrator), and switched to the `C:\Python27\Scripts` directory. I then typed: `pip --version`

The only thing happens is the command prompt moves down 2 lines. No error messages are returned. See output of command window above.

How can I get pip to run on Windows 10?

Comment: My python system variables on Windows 10 are:

Comment: Ignore my duplicate suggestion (which I've now deleted) - I didn't read the question carefully - sorry.